# Laravel blade templates, foreach variable inside URL::to?

Tags: templates, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm creating a basic list view of posts, and need a link to the 'edit' page.

I'm using blade, and what I have is a table, with a foreach loop, showing each post along with edit/delete buttons.

What I wanted to do is use blade's URL::to for the links to the edit and delete pages, to ensure consistant links.

The code I've tried using (remember this is inside a foreach loop hence the $post->id var) is this:

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('admin/posts/edit/$post->id') }}" class="btn btn-mini btn-primary">Edit Post</a>
```

However this does not work. I've also tried

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('admin/posts/edit/<?php echo $post->id; ?>') }}" class="btn btn-mini btn-primary">Edit Post</a>
```

which also doesnt work.

I dont get any error, the link literally ends up being:

```
http://domain.dev/admin/posts/$post->id
```

Is there any way of working around this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using php variable ($post) within a string with a single `'`. In this case it just outputs the name of the variable. Try this:

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('admin/posts/edit/' . $post->id) }}" class="btn btn-mini btn-primary">Edit Post</a>
```

Hope this helps.
Vlad

Answer (score 14):

vlad has already given the right answer to your question but be aware that you can also directly link to your controller action via `URL::action`:

```
<a href="{{ URL::action('Admin\PostsController@edit', $post->id) }}">Edit</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  This helped solve my problem where I thought a link to the action would be aware of variables set that match variables in the route.  Not so. I had to pass it as the second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The `{{ }}` are equal to `<?php echo ;?>`

if you put single `'`

`<?php echo '$hello' ?>` = $hello

but if you put double `' (")` -> `<?php "$hello" ;?>` = Hello World (just one example)

You need to write something like `{{ URL::to("admin/posts/edit/$post->id") }}`

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work

```
<a href="{{ url('test/'.$post->id.'/view') }}"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
<a href="{{URL::to('/')}}/admin/posts/edit/{{$post->id}}">Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had an issue with this in Laravel 5 so thought Id pop it in even if the question is old. Resolved my issue using

`{{ URL::to('/box').'/'.$box->id }}`

or
`{{ url('/box').'/'.$box->id }}`

Answer (score 0):

Also you may use `route()` helper to generate url by name of route. For example, definition of route:

```
Route::get('/test/mypage/{id}', 'MyController@myAction')->name('my_route_name');
```

Code in your view:

```
<a href="{{ route('my_route_name', $row['id']) }}">{{ $row['name'] }}</a>
```